# Regex to find the second value in all 3D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, regex

I have some spatial (x,y,z) data in a text file in the following format:

```
(0.00024955 0 0) (3.06169e-05 -1.51066e-08 -2.54633e-08) (3.02857e-05 1.38107e-08 -2.52017e-08) (0.00024955 0 0)
```

that I want to transform to an array of only the second values. I used regex for this, and it naturally only grabbed the first number, which I wanted at first. But now, I only want the y values. This is the regex I have that grabs the first (the x) value:

```
Ux[i] = Ux[i].strip(str_chars)
Ux[i] = re.search(r'-?[\d.]+(?:e-?\d+)?', Ux[i]).group()
```

Where str_chars = '()'. Any ideas on how I can change my regex to produce the y value?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), first on `) (` to split into "tuples" and then on space to get the middle value. You can convert that to a number (if desired) using [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html?highlight=float#float):

```
txt = '(0.00024955 0 0) (3.06169e-05 -1.51066e-08 -2.54633e-08) (3.02857e-05 1.38107e-08 -2.52017e-08) (0.00024955 0 0)'

mids = [float(t.split()[1]) for t in txt.split(') (')]
print(mids)
```

Output:

```
[0.0, -1.51066e-08, 1.38107e-08, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `re.findall` here with an appropriate regex:

```
inp = "(0.00024955 0 0) (3.06169e-05 -1.51066e-08 -2.54633e-08) (3.02857e-05 1.38107e-08 -2.52017e-08) (0.00024955 0 0)"
nums = re.findall(r'\(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:e-?\d+)? (-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:e-?\d+)?) -?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:e-?\d+)?\)', inp)
print(nums)
```

This prints:

```
['0', '-1.51066e-08', '1.38107e-08', '0']
```

The regex pattern I used matched an entire `(x, y, z)` tuple, each number of which is matched using the following regex pattern:

```
-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:e-?\d+)?
```

Explanation:

```
-?           match optional leading negative sign
\d+          match one or more whole digits
(?:\.\d+)?   match optional decimal component
(?:e-?\d+)?  match optional +/- exponent
```